# Why the buildmaster does not configure ENV of buildslave?

Tags: linux, buildbot

I'm facing a really weird issue on buildbot, setting the env property.
Strange thing is that I have some configuration where the env configuration is working as expected.

The scenario that is showing that misbehavior is the following:

- buildmaster v0.8.8 running on gentoo with python 2.7
- buildlslave v.0.8.9 running on CentOs 5.10 with python 2.6

the slave has the following shell command:

```
qmake = ShellCommand(
  command = ["qmake"],
  warnOnWarnings = True,
  haltOnFailure = True,
  workdir = nr.iqac_platform_build_root,
  name = "qmake",
  env = nr.centos510_64bit_env_dict )
```

where

```
centos510_64bit_env_dict = { 'PATH': ["/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin", "${PATH}"] }
```

Problem is that the environment is not properly set and the shell command fails.
From the master log I can seen:

```
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] ShellCommand.startCommand(cmd=<RemoteShellCommand '['qmake']'>)
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-]   cmd.args = {'workdir': 'build/nr_libs/uniqlogger/lib', 'timeout': 1200, 'env': None, 'want_stdout': 1, 'usePTY': 'slave-config', 'maxTime': None, 'logEnviron': True, 'initial_stdin': None, 'want_stderr': 1, 'logfiles': {}}
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] <RemoteShellCommand '['qmake']'>: RemoteCommand.run [6]
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] command '['qmake']' in dir 'build/nr_libs/uniqlogger/lib'
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [Broker,0,192.168.23.230] <RemoteShellCommand '['qmake']'> rc=1
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] closing log <buildbot.status.logfile.LogFile instance at 0x20ba488>
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] releaseLocks(<buildbot.steps.shell.ShellCommand object at 0x20943d0>): []
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-]  step 'qmake' complete: failure
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-]  <Build iqac_platform_centos510_64b>: build finished
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] sending mail (780 bytes) to ['s.borghese@netresults.it']
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] Starting factory <twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTPSenderFactory instance at 0x20ba368>
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [-] releaseLocks(<BuildSlave 'centos510_64bit'>): []
2014-08-09 16:14:05+0200 [ESMTPSender,client] Stopping factory <twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTPSenderFactory instance at 0x20ba368>
```

To me the above log means that the env is not set. Of course I might be wrong, that's why I'm asking for some advice.
As stated before, I already used the env configuration property with another slave running on MacOSX (cannot retrieve the slave version as the host is down right now)

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Do you think the slave version > master version can be an issue?

The slave has been installed using easy_install and that's the version retrieved by the setuptools fro python 2.6

Comment: What is `nr` here?  From a brief look and an attempt to replicate this, it looks like `nr.centos510_64bit_env_dict` is None.

Comment: I have a file with some consts I use in my config files. This file contains the definition for centos510_64bit_env_dict and is imported as: **from buildvars import NrBuildVars as nr** so the variable is not supposed to be None

Comment: Right, bit *is* it None?  That would be a good place to bisect the problem -- if it's None, you have one problem.  If it's not None, then you have a different problem.

Comment: @djmitche: I'll do some more investigation and will update on this...

Comment: Did you try to look at the stdio from your slave to see what Path it is using at runtime?